# get_storage package data remains even after reinstalling in Flutter Mobile App

Tags: flutter, local-storage

Flutter Application delete in my physical device.
But get_storage package Data remains even after reinstalling.

Please help me.

Comment: Try calling box.erase(); in main.dart init() method

Answer (score 0):

go to the `AndroidManifest.xml` file and add the following to prevent saving backups for the application:

```
<application 
 android:allowBackup="false" 
 android:fullBackupOnly="false"
 //...
 />
```

as I searched, on API 23 ( Android 6 ) an automatic backup will be executed for applications,

Comment: can you tell me how did you fix it